# How to Join tables in laravel with a value from previously joined table?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have a table in laravel which tracks recent views of posts by users. Here is its controller

```
$contents = RecentView::where('user_id', $loggedUser)
                        ->with('posts.user')
                        ->with(['posts.note' => function($query) use($loggedUser){
                            $query->where('user_id', $loggedUser);
                        }])
                        ->with(['posts.tags' => function($query) use($loggedUser){
                            $query->where('user_id', $loggedUser);
                        }])
                        ->with(['posts.savedpost' => function($query) use($loggedUser){
                            $query->where('user_id', $loggedUser);
                        }])
                        ->with(['following' => function($query) use($loggedUser){
                            $query->where('user_id', $loggedUser)
                            ->where('follower_id', 'id');
                        }])
                        ->paginate(12)->toArray();
```

I always gel blank values in 'following'. i want to join 'follow' table using 'user_id' field from 'posts' table.

my model is as follows:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\FeedPost', 'id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function following()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Follow');
    }
```

can someone tell me how i can do this?

Comment: Can you post the complete code of the controller method? If you are trying to get all recent views for the logged in user with following records of users whom the logged in user is following then follower_id needs to be ckecked against an array of ids of users whom the logged user is following

Comment: `where('follower_id', 'id')` means you're asking for an entry from the `following` table where `follower_id` and `id` column are the same. I suspect that's not what you intend.

Comment: And it's hard to say from the information provided here but it seems like you could reduce this code a lot by running this query from the point of view of `$loggedUser` instead of `RecentView`. This would not require all the work with query builder, because you should have relationships set up like `$loggedUser->followers`, `$loggedUser->following`, `$loggedUser->posts`, etc.

Comment: @miken32 ```->join('follows', function($join) use($loggedUser){
                            $join->on('follows.user_id', '=', $loggedUser);
                            $join->on('follows.follower_id','=', 'posts.user_id');```

Comment: now i am getting following error: ```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `recent_views` inner join `follows` on `follows`.`user_id` = 235 and `follows`.`follower_id` = posts.user_id where `user_id` = 235)```